# Minimize or disable cmd window when execute pytesseract code Python

Tags: python

I have this problem:

My code take screenshot for later recognize image with pytesseract. The code works perfect but cmd windows of pytesseract sometimes appears in area I need take the next screenshot image.

Is posible disable cmd window open?

[image]

```
import pytesseract


start_time = time.clock()

c=0
while c < 10:
    imc1=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(369,281,379,296))
    imc1.save("images/table/c1.jpg","png")
    y = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('images/table/c1.jpg'),config='-psm 10000')

    print y

    c+=1


print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

Comment: `start /min tesseract` should run tesseract minimized

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want start minimized when I run code from idle I think the code you write is for when I want run tesseract.py

Comment: pythonw instead of python runs without console.

However the program in your screenshot is tesseract, so it seems like you want to run that minimized...

Comment: Sorry but I try to edit code and I'm not able to run minimized. I read tesseract manual and no have any reference to this thing. You can write an example please?